# guid in System.Guid

Tags: guid, uniqueidentifier

As per MSDN, they describe System.Guid.NewGuid() as ..

```
The chance that the value of the new Guid will be all zeros or equal to any other Guid is very **low**
```

Will it be a bad idea to set customerID of Customer table to "uniqueidentifier" and generate the unique id using the System.Guid.NewGuid() ? How can I assure the method will generate only unique IDs ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Random is System.Guid.NewGuid()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467271/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very good reasons to use Guid as ID, I would recommend against using Guid as key. Guids take a lot of space in a database, and provide no benefit in common scenarios. Plus they do not play well with indexes.

Why don't you set the CustomerID as an integer and set it to auto-generate its value when you insert a new record?