# Coverting Guid to string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, guid

I am creating a application and I wanted to try and use GUIDs. I am using Entity Framework code first and LINQ so I thought the easiest way would be to use

```
string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var acc = new v_Account();   
acc.v_AcctGuid = guid;
```

And then store my GUIDs as type string in my database. Is this a bad practice? Is a GUID really just a globally unique randomly generated string potentially?

I am pretty sure it is going to work but I just don't want to face problems down the road or create a vulnerability by doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467271/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid ...'How Random is a Guid'? ...Although, why don't you just have an incrementing integer for their AccountNumber...why does it need to be a Guid?

Comment: Why are you converting GUID values to strings instead of just using them directly, i.e. defining the `v_AcctGuid` property as type `Guid`?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on `GUID` also hopefully you are not going to use this as a potential `Primary Key` `Integer values are much quicker when Indexing off of than Strings` GUIDS are said to be `Unique` I don't think that you have the time to even test the accuracy of if a GUID would ever repeat itself...I would recommend doing some more research before you put in too much `Wasted Effort`

Comment: A GUID is really an array of 16 bytes. It's merely represented as a hex string and broken into parts to make it a bit more human usable. But at the end of the day all it is is 16 bytes and it's best to store it as the byte array instead of a string, as the byte array will take up half as much space. MS SQL Server actually has a GUID column type, if you're using that.

Comment: You're not saying what you are going to do with the GUIDs so we can't tell you whether it's dangerous or not. GUIDs are just a piece of data. Everybody's guess is that you want to use them as unique values for Primary Keys; that would be a bad use of GUIDs. Use your database's facilities for Identity fields. If you are trying to use them for something else, please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GUID maps directly to a MSSQL database as a `uniqueidentifier` type.  So there is no need to stringify it.

Just use it directly:

```
acc.v_AcctGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Assuming:

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid v_AcctGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what if he doesn't use MSSQL? What if the db he uses doesn't support GUIDs?

Comment: @dutzu that is why I mention the database in my answer.  Also, most people using EF are using MSSQL.

Comment: `dutzu` its the same thing in `Sql Server` that's like asking what if the DB he's using doesn't support a `string` come on now... `Dutzu` here is some good brush up reading to answer your questions / comments http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/generate_new_guid_uniqueidentifier_in_sql_server.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the db you are targeting does not support GUIDs (like `SQLite` for instance) then it's ok to store as string and then expose them to the Business Layer as GUID making the necessary conversions on the getter and setter of a property of type GUID that masks the string property of the entity.