# How can I get a random sized list of random entries out of an IEnumerable<> in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Question
{
    public int    QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and in a variable I have:

```
IEnumerable<Question> _questions = GetQuestions.Get();
```

How can I take the collection of questions that are in the variable _questions and return at random a list of between 1 and 4 random questions out of the collection?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567 and then just use `.Take()` with the number of questions you want (just use `Random.Next` to get the random number between 1 and 4).

Answer (score 6):

You can *shuffle* the list first and then use `Take()`

```
var result = _questions.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                       .Take(new Random().Next(4) + 1);
```

Comment: Make the parameter to `Take` be a random int between 1-4 and that would be a full answer.

Comment: @Tim - The first _random_ four.

Comment: @Oded - Sorry - our comments crossed.  I was referring to Cuong's answer, not yours.  You are correct - make it a random number between 1 and 4 and it's good. :)

Comment: use a random object inside the take parameter.

Comment: Remember that GUIDs, while unique, aren't necessarily *guaranteed* to be random: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467271/how-random-is-system-guid-newguid

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: You are right, it might get `0` as result, so ` + 1` would be perfect. Thanks

Comment: Also, use a proper shuffle. What's the point of O(n log n) when you can have O(n)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to make a single pass through a sequence of unknown size to select a random set of N items:

```
public static List<T> RandomlyChooseItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int n, Random rng)
{
    var result = new List<T>(n);
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (index < n)
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            int r = rng.Next(0, index + 1);

            if (r < n)
                result[r] = item;
        }

        ++index;
    }

    return result;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Question> questions = ...;
Random rng = new Random();
int questionCount = rng.Next(1, 5); // Get between 1 and 4 questions.

List<Question> randomQuestions = RandomlyChooseItems(questions, questionCount, rng);
```

This isn't usually much more efficient than copying the items into an array and doing a [`Fisher-Yates shuffle`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but can be useful if the size of the list to choose from is very large and the number of items to choose is relatively small, since you only need to store the chosen items and not the original list of items.