# sql server 2008 not generating random value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, random

I'm having a problem with random values being generated for each row in a result set in SQL Server 2008.  I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247554/random-number-on-sql-without-using-newid), but upon implementing the proposed answer, I saw the same problem as before.  When running the query I have provided below, it seems that the same values will sometimes show up in consecutive rows, even though I'm calling for a new `NEWID()` with each row.

```
DECLARE @Id int = 0
DECLARE @Counter int = 1
DECLARE @Value int

CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
id int identity(1,1)
,Value int
)

WHILE @Counter < 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Table1 (Value)
    SELECT CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100000 as INT)
    SET @Counter += 1
END

SET @Counter = 0
WHILE @Counter < 5
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @Value = T.Value
        ,@Id = T.id
    FROM #Table1 T
    WHERE T.id = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100000 as INT) + 1 + @Counter

    IF @Id <> 0
        SELECT @Value AS Value ,@Id as ID
    SET @Counter += 1
END
DROP TABLE #Table1
```

If I change the `INT` to a `BIGINT`, as suggested in the link I provided, nothing is solved, so I don't believe that it's an "overflow" issue.

Comment: Edit:  Actually, I'm adding the counter to the `WHERE` statement here, so it can't be an issue with generating the random number, but rather with updating the variables, am I correct?

Comment: You never set @Id back to 0 after displaying it, so it will display again on the next iteration of the loop if nothing is found.

Comment: This is not the case.  The double rows happen with Ids and Values other than 0. Also, @Id is updated via the select statement during each iteration, regardless of whether or not it is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the calculation out of the select, I don't get the doubled rows:

```
DECLARE @Id int = 0
DECLARE @Counter int = 1
DECLARE @Value int
-- new variable
DECLARE @DERIVED INT 

CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
id int identity(1,1)
,Value int
)

WHILE @Counter < 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Table1 (Value)
    SELECT CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100000 as INT)
    SET @Counter += 1
END

SET @Counter = 0
WHILE @Counter < 5
BEGIN
--set here to remove calculation from the select
    SET @DERIVED = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100000 as INT) + 1 + @Counter;
    SELECT
        @Value = T.Value
        ,@Id = T.id
    FROM #Table1 T
    WHERE T.id = @DERIVED

    IF @Id <> 0
        SELECT @Value AS Value ,@Id as ID;
    SET @Counter += 1
END
DROP TABLE #Table1
```

I'm seeing the duplicates every time with the pseudorandom generator inside the select.  Oddly enough, I get about the same frequency of duplicates on the insert loop whether or not the calculation is inside the insert... select.  It could be coincidence, since we are dealing with a randomly selected number.  Note also, that since you're adding to the pseudorandom result, the results aren't technically duplicates.  They're descending sequences:

```
11111 + 1 + 1 = 11113
11110 + 1 + 2 = 11113
```

Same overall result, different pseudorandom result.  However, if I change

```
CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100000 as INT) + 1 + @Counter
```

to

```
CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100000 as INT) + @Counter + @Counter
```

I still consistently get duplicates.  That implies that the optimizer may be caching/re-using values, at least on the select.  I'd call that improper for a non-deterministic function call.  I get similar results on 10.0.1600 and 10.50.1600 (2008 RTM and 2008R2 RTM).

Comment: Jason, thanks for your effort.  I see the same results you do.  I also was able to eliminate duplicates by setting `@Id` and `@Value NULL` after incrementing the counter.  Thanks again.