# What are the chances of getting the same GUID in 1 billion iterations?

Tags: .net, guid

I am working on a project where I need to generate approximately 1 billion GUIDs.

I know GUIDs are not guaranteed to be unique but are unique almost all of the time.

If I generated a billion GUIDs, what is the probability that there will be a match?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are GUID collisions possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184869/are-guid-collisions-possible)

Comment: Over how long a period of time are you going to be generating the GUIDs?

Comment: it will all be done in one batch, so however long it takes to do that

Comment: You'll need to ensure that enough time passes between each GUID generation to allow the time to become unique again. I don't know how long that is, that's your only concern. I'd recommend multiple computers working on this in parallel!

Comment: @overslacked the time stamp value has a resolution of 100ns, so assuming it is got from a timer with similar resolution it should be OK, as you aren't going to generate more than 2^14 GUIDs between time stamp increments on current conventional hardware (a quad core at 4GHz would need to be able to create a GUID for a quarter a cpu  cycle; so an increment, an or, two moves probably need 64 cores to start getting close).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Blogpost: GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren’t](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823)

The .NET GUID consists of

- 60 bits of timestamp,
- 48 bits of computer identifier,
- 14 bits of uniquifier, and
- six bits are fixed

So the UUID probability quoted by Oscar does not work here. But if you create all your 1 billion GUIDs from one computer, there is no chance to get a duplicate (except you are playing with the clock ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating the GUIds from the same machine and using the same algorithm then you will not get a collision.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

n                 probability

68,719,476,736 = 2^36 = 0.0000000000000004 = 4 × 10^−16)

2,199,023,255,552 = 2^41 = 0.0000000000004 = (4 × 10^−13)

70,368,744,177,664 = 2^46 = 0.0000000004 = (4 × 10^−10)

Comment: He's talking about .NET GUIDs, they are not entirely random, like assumed in the article. There are parts caused by time and processor id(?) ... still the chance of getting a duplicate in 1 billion GUIDs is very unlikely on the same machine it may be even impossible.