# How large can an id get in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, integer, primary-key

I am using postgresql, and was wondering how large

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

can get compared to

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

In java an `int` is 4 bytes (32 bits) so it can get up to 2,147,483,647. Is this the case in postgresql?  If so does that mean I cannot go past 2,147,483,647 rows?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is a handy chart for PostgreSQL:

```
Name        Storage Size    Description                       Range
smallint    2 bytes         small-range integer               -32768 to +32767
integer     4 bytes         usual choice for integer          -2147483648 to +2147483647
bigint      8 bytes         large-range integer               -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
smallserial 2 bytes         small autoincrementing integer    1 to 32767
serial      4 bytes         autoincrementing integer          1 to 2147483647
bigserial   8 bytes         large autoincrementing integer    1 to 9223372036854775807
```

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Your assessment is right, you'd run out of unique ID's if you used a data type that was insufficient.

Comment: .. but if you use a `bigint` (or `bigserial`, which is the same thing) [you really, really won't run out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132939/what-happens-when-i-exhaust-a-bigint-generated-key-how-to-handle-it/13133035#13133035).

Answer (score 4):

> [The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

A `bigserial` is 8 bytes long. If that is not enough it is possible to use the [128 bits uuid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-uuid.html):

```
create table t (
    id uuid primary key
);
insert into t (id)
select uuid_generate_v1mc();
select * from t;
                  id                  
--------------------------------------
 916bf7e6-f0c2-11e2-8d14-d372d5ab075f
```

The `uuid_generate_v1mc` function is provided by the [uuid-ossp module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/uuid-ossp.html)

The main advantage of the uuid functions is that they generate an id that is very likely to be unique among different systems. A `serial` will have collisions between those systems.

Comment: And here I thought the trillion record tables I deal with were large, can't imagine needing more than nine quintillion ID's.

Comment: Heh... people afraid of exhausing a `bigint` key [just haven't done the maths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132939/what-happens-when-i-exhaust-a-bigint-generated-key-how-to-handle-it/13133035#13133035). `uuid` keys can be very handy for distributed systems but are unnecessary for key exhaustion issues..

Comment: @CraigRinger due to the birthday paradox bigint can have conflicts between keys long before it is "exhausted". UUIDs have 128 bits to avoid that problem.

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth If you are generating keys at random, yes. With BIGSERIAL sequences, no.