# Odds of colision GUID

Tags: .net, collision, guid

While I was digging [source of StackID](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackID/blob/master/OpenIdProvider/Models/User.cs#L227) I saw [this line](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackID/blob/master/OpenIdProvider/Models/User.cs#L227) which confused me,

```
while (db.Users.Any(u => u.ProviderId == provider))
                provider = Current.UniqueId();
```

There are lots of sources that say finally

> Yes there is an odds of collision GUID but it's very.....very
>   miniscule, ignore it

After I read those articles, I've never thought again about odds of collision, just ignored it until I saw the code above.

Should we check the collision, even if it's odds very miniscule, have you been checking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are GUID collisions possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184869/are-guid-collisions-possible)

Comment: @RB., I don't think this is a duplicate, I just wonder why stackexchange developers did this?