# Change key type of IdentityUser to int in razor-page application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I want to customize `IdentityUser` to add some attributes and change the key type to `int`. I tried and followed this Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

In the documentation, it says:

> In IdentityModels.cs, change the ApplicationUser class to inherit from IdentityUser

However I don't find a `IdentityModel.cs` in my project. That's why I don't think that this documentaion applies to my Razor-pages web app.

How do I go about changing the `IdentityUser` key type to `int`?

Comment: The (German) documentation for Identity in ASP.NET Core is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I've subclassed IdentityUser to create my own ApplicationUser class and added custom properties to that. I'm not sure you can change the default key. Is there a specific reason you can't use the default GUID? Otherwise you may need to roll your own classes

Comment: @BradPatton I just thought it was nicer to have `int` keys so that the database can autoincrement them. When using GUIDs I have to generate and check it's not (by chance) in the database yet.

Comment: @Jimmy For any future reader: While I personally still prefer `int` keys (in most cases), checking whether a GUID key already exists (as per my previous comment) isn't really necessary as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184897/10758800) S.O. answer